# how to create session in asp

Tags: asp-classic

how to create session in asp??

I am using this in my PHP code

Here is my php session

```
$sid = CreatePSession();
```

Now I want to use this in asp how it is possible ?

Comment: ASP creates a session for you. You don't have to create one by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a simple as assigning a value like this:

```
Session("mySessionKey") = "My value"
```

The `Session` collection is globally accessible. As is the `Application` collection which pretty much works in the same way with the difference that it is application spanning.

In your PHP code, you are calling the `CreatePSession` function and what that returns is something you have to check in order to do the same thing in ASP. My guess is that it is giving you a userId or something.

Comment: :) how can i use this in my session as in my Question can u please chang this

Comment: What are you using $sid for? What is it in your application?

Comment: :) $sid is used for session id while CreatePSession  is the function

Comment: Do you even have the CreatePSession function in you ASP code? And what is it suppose to do? 
`session_start()` is not used in ASP. Please note that ASP is not the same thing as PHP. They solve the same problem, but they do it in different ways.

Comment: :) Yes I HAVE i can change all my CreatePSession function in to asp, yes i know that asp and php are differ so i want to know an alternate options for session_start().

Comment: What would you like you `session_start()` to perform then? In ASP, there is no `session_start()` as the Session collection is globally available at all times. You can just assign a value to the session and you're done.

Comment: In your case it would be `Session("sid") = CreatePSession()`

Comment: :) ok but i think session_start() command start the session for whole page not for particular case, but as u told me it is not possible in asp, so i think it is the disadvantage of asp

Comment: @ Mikael Östberg:) after using this i got an Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A000D)
Type mismatch: 'CreatePSession'

Comment: Firstly i am using this dim sid sid=CreatePSession() after that on the other page i am using what u told me Session("sid") = CreatePSession()

Comment: I think looking into an ASP tutorial could be beneficial to you. I don't think we can get any longer here. Here is one: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/default.asp

Comment: @John: Are you trying to share session state *between PHP and ASP*? So that PHP and ASP use the "same session"?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this to create asp session

```
Session("test")="anyvalue"
```

Comment: :)how can i change this $sid = CreatePSession();

Comment: Strong type the variable based on the return type of  CreatePSession();. if you dont know the return type then use var sid=CreatePSession();

Comment: Pareen Vatani:) IN asp it works ????Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript compilation (0x800A0401)
Expected end of statement

Comment: Try this  dim sid=CreatePSession()

Comment: :) dim sid    sid=CreatePSession()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4191/discussion-between-pareen-vatani-and-john)